# convert DB array output to Eloquent Model for using API Resources

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to use DB::select and DB::table in my laravel project
how can i get Eloquent Models from them ?
they returns array and can't used with API Resources

Comment: Why not use Eloquent model, what is your use case where you can't use that instead of DB::table

Comment: why can't be used with API Resources? what's missing?

Comment: DB::table and select will return an array containing object for each record... so what you are missing from those object that Eloquent gave you for API resources?